# EF Core 多対多テーブルへのデータ追加でトラッキングエラー

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

EntityFrameworkCoreにてSQLiteを使用したWPFアプリケーションを作成しています。
ソースを下記GitHubにアップしましたので、ローカルにて実行して頂くと
現象が分かりやすいかと思います。

https://github.com/Nao05215/OpeTimeCalendar

まず、各日付ごとにプロダクトがあり、その中にワークと作業時間があります。
そこで下記の手順を実行します。

①任意の日付にプロダクトを追加します。（画面右上「Add Product」を選択して任意のコード、名前を入力）
②追加されたプロダクト内にワークを追加します。（Productにマウスオーバーで現れる「Add Work」を選択）
③プルダウンから任意の大項目を選択。（ワーク内一番左）
④プルダウンから任意の小項目を選択。（ワーク内中央）
⑤Ctrl+Sで保存
⑥アプリケーションを一度終了して再起動
⑦手順②③④を再度すべて同じ項目で入力する
⑧Ctrl+Sで保存

ここで以下のエラーが発生します。
発生個所は「40_DataBase\DataBase.cs」内の89行目「db.Add(monthInfo);」部分です。

```
The instance of entity type 'Work' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Index'} is already being tracked.
When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
```

しかし、手順⑥の再起動を行わなかった場合、同じワークを追加してもエラーは発生しません。
多対多テーブルの対象はProduct, Workで結合テーブル「ProductWork」を用いています。

アプリ再起動を行った場合、行わなかった場合で振る舞いが変わってしまう原因が
全く理解できず、エラー発生の理由が掴めない為、ご教示お願いします。

Comment: プロジェクトにCustomControls.1.0.1が無くてビルドやデバッグが出来ないようです。

Comment: @kunif ご指摘ありがとうございます。自作nugetパッケージです。このdllを含めてGithubにアップする方法はありますでしょうか…

Comment: やったことは無いですが、CustomControlsをプロジェクトごとソリューションにコピーするか、ビルド後のbinフォルダをdllとかlibに名前を変えてdebug/releaseともにコピーして、参照先をそちらに変更するとかでしょうか？

Comment: @kunif ありがとうございます。bin/Debugフォルダをgitに含めてコミットしました。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: [EF Core2で実行したSQLの引数をログに出力する](https://blog.beaglesoft.net/entry/2017/11/02/151445)の記事を適用して`optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();`してみたところ、`same key value for {'Index'}`の部分が`key value '{Index: 5100}'`に変わりました(`5100`はその時入力した小項目の値)。何か小項目の値に同じものがあってはいけない設定とかコーディングが行われているのでは？

Comment: @kunif すみません、最初に記述しておくべきでした。小項目のIndexはデータベース上、一意制約があります。そのため、DataBaseクラスのSaveMonthInfo内でTrackerからWorkの追跡は外すようにして、Add/Modify等を行わないようにしました。これによって同じIndex(ここでは小項目にあたります)が登録されても問題ない様にしたつもりなのですが、アプリを再起動した時のみ、同じIndexの項目を複数追跡してしまいます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

データベースやEntityFrameworkに触れたことは無いので、トンデモな内容かもしれませんが、何かのヒントになれば。

元の処理的には、同じ内容のものがあるか検索して、有ったら削除してから、今回のものを追加する、と言う風になっていると見ました。

ここで今回は、追加する時点の`db.Add()`で例外になっている訳ですが、上記の処理を行うなら`db.Update()`に変えても良いのでは？と考えました。
実験したらそれでも例外が発生したので、何か類似の代替手段は無いかとIntellisenseで眺めていたら`Attach()`と言うのがあったので例外時にはそちらに切り替えてみたら、それらしく動作するようになりました。

以下のような感じですね。
元々の`var sel = db.MonthInfos`から`db.Add(monthInfo);`までの処理は削除しています。

```
public static void SaveMonthInfo(MonthInfo monthInfo, bool isNotify = true)
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new Context())
        {
            try
            {
                db.Update(monthInfo);
            }
            catch
            {
                db.Attach(monthInfo);
            }
            foreach (var item in db.Works)
            {
                db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Detached;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        if (isNotify) Notification.Notify($"{monthInfo.Year}年{monthInfo.Month}月のデータを保存しました");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.TargetSite.Name);
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        if (isNotify) Notification.Notify("データの保存に失敗しました");
    }
}
```

知識や理論は何も無く、変えてみたら動くようになったレベルですが、興味を引いたら調べてみてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。掲示して頂いたコードで想定通りの動作を確認出来ました。私自身今回初めての挑戦なので根本的に使い方が理解できていないのだと感じました。何故そうなるのか、調べてみたいと思います。幾度に渡りありがとうございました。